# How to specify username and password for Hgsubversion

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion, hgrc

I would like to know how to specify user name and password to be used in pushing changes to subversion repository from HG using Hgsubversion

I would like to know where in my repository I should set

```
   "hgsubversion.username", "hgsubversion.password"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look at first

> **'hg help subversion'**  for more details.

The settings must be added to the

> **user-global ~/.hgrc file**

The local settings will have no effect

```
See 'hg help config' -- that explains that when we call a configuration
setting 'foo.bar', then you enter it in your configuration file as

[foo]
bar = something

[hgsubversion]
username = < your_name >
password = < your_secret >
```